Redis-server with tls and Systemd on Ubuntu Server 24.04
I have redis-server set up and sudo systemctl restart redis-server works just fine however when I implement tls support then systemctl fails with no useful error message and nothing in the logs, however redis-server still works manually with this command
 ./redis-server --tls-port 6379 --port 0 --tls-cert-file ./redis.crt --tls-key-file ./redis.key --tls-ca-cert-file ./ca.crt

I've tried with Ubuntu Server 24.04 and also Debian 12 (Bookworm) - same issue
Does anyone know how to get it working as a systemd upstart job with tls enabled?

Even if they are not helpful, can you share the logs? Check running processes.

I believe this relates to the relative path for the SSL you set when starting up the redis-server. You must configure the absolute path for the SSL instead in the systemd. So, the startup script of Redis in systems should be as follows:
 ./redis-server --tls-port 6379 --port 0 --tls-cert-file /absolute_path_cert/redis.crt --tls-key-file /absolute_path_cert/redis.key --tls-ca-cert-file /absolute_path_cert/ca.crt

Another option is to configure the SSL in the redis.conf and put the SSL configuration there:
#TLS config
tls-port 6379
tls-cert-file /app/tls/redis.crt
tls-key-file /app/tls/redis.key
tls-ca-cert-file /app/tls/ca.crt

Later, in the /etc/systemd/system/redis.service file, you can configure the redis-server to call the redis.conf:
root@redis-s-1vcpu-2gb-sgp1-02:~# cat /etc/systemd/system/redis.service
[Unit]
Description=Advanced key-value store
After=network.target
Documentation=http://redis.io/documentation, man:redis-server(1)

[Service]
Type=notify
ExecStart=/usr/bin/redis-server /etc/redis/redis.conf
ExecStop=/bin/kill -s TERM $MAINPID
PIDFile=/run/redis/redis-server.pid
TimeoutStopSec=0
Restart=always
User=redis
Group=redis
RuntimeDirectory=redis
RuntimeDirectoryMode=2755

Hope that helps!

It was my mistake, the cert files were in my home directory so the redis user did not have access to them
